# jquery plupload inside an accordion. The latter does not auto height

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion, plupload

i am using a plupload plugin inside an accordion. I first create the the plupload and then I create the accordion.

The plupload creates well... but the accordion height is not resized so that the whole plupload is seen sinside it. The height is about 50 px instead and the vertical scroll appears.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
function createUploader()
{
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue("destroy");

    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
        url: '/upload.php',
        max_file_size: '10mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,
        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: {width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90},
        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
            {title: "Archivos de imagen", extensions: "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title: "Archivos comprimidos", extensions: "zip,rar"},
            {title: "Documentos", extensions: "doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pdf,pptx,csv,txt"}
        ],
        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });
}

function creaDialogoAdjuntos()
{
    createUploader();

    $('#acordeon_adjuntos').accordion();
 }


$(function() {
    creaDialogoAdjuntos();
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
    <div id="acordeon_adjuntos">
        <h3>Nuevo Adjunto</h3>
        <div>        
            <form id="attach" action="{{ path('_renombra_archivos') }}">
                <div id="uploader">
                    <p>Su navegador no tiene soporte Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus o HTML5.</p>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="adjComId" name="compromiso" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <h4>Adjuntos</h4>
        <div>
            <table id="adjuntos_compromisos"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
            <div id="adjuntos_paginacion"></div>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Any help to solve this will be appreciated.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: have you tried to delay initialization of your accordion in the PostInit handler of your uploader, like this : `init: {PostInit: function(upldr){$('#acordeon_adjuntos').accordion();}}`